# How can order by last replies?

Tags: sql

I have two tables the first is the 'users' the second is the 'posts',
the 'users' have two columns:

```
1 id 
2 username
```

the 'posts' have five columns:

```
1 p_id
2 uid
3 post_id
4 content
5 date
```

the posts as defined have the value '0' in `post_id` and the replies have the value `p_id` in `post_id`. My query is

```
SELECT id,username,p_id,uid,post_id,content,date
FROM users
inner join posts
ON users.id=posts.uid
WHERE post_id='0'
ORDER BY p_id DESC
```

but I want to order by the last replies like in a forum.

Comment: ORDER BY `date`

Comment: A: RTM => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html if you're using mysql.

Comment: Plus, the RDBMS is unclear as to which one you're using and the php tag contains no code to support the question.

Comment: There is no PHP relation here, this is all some sort of SQL. MySQL maybe? `ORDER BY p_id DESC` should be easy enough to change to `date` though..

Comment: change to date not working .....I want order the posts wich have the value post_id='0' by the last reply for exampl my post is the last when a user reply to it the post will be the first

Comment: Your sample data and query seem to have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause to find the latest reply date and order by that column. If the post has no replys, use the date of the post instead:

```
SELECT id,username,p_id,uid,post_id,content,date, (
    SELECT MAX(date) FROM posts r WHERE r.post_id = p.p_id
) AS last_reply_date
FROM users
inner join posts p
ON users.id=p.uid
WHERE p.post_id='0'
ORDER BY COALESCE(last_reply_date, p.date) DESC
```